# django slice filter breaks template for tinymce safe content

Tags: django, django-tinymce

I have contents which were published using tinymce editor. Now, I want to show my content, that's why I have to use safe filter. But, whenever I'm trying to use slice or truncate filter, the template breaks. 
this is my HTML code.

```
{% extends 'blog/frontend/layouts/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="card border-primary">
  {% for post in posts %}
  <div class="card my-2 mx-1">

    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.permalink %}" class="text-primary">{{ post.title }}</a></h5>
      <hr>
      <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" alt="Card image" width="85%" class="mx-auto d-block">
      <p class="card-text mt-1">
          {{ post.content|truncatewords:50|safe}}
      </p>
      <hr>
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="px-2 py-0 my-auto">
            <h6><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>&nbsp;<a href="#">{{ post.author.username }}</a></h6>
        </div>
        <div class="px-2 py-0 my-auto">
            <h6>Date posted: <span class="text-info">{{ post.date_posted|date:"d M, Y" }}</span></h6>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-auto px-2 my-auto ">
            <a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.permalink %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read more</a>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**These are the image, first one without sliceor turncate filter, 2nd and 3rd one are with them.**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it was a stupid question to ask. Just in case anyone else is facing this kind of problem, use `truncatechars_html` or `truncatewords_html` just like this: `{{ post.content|truncatewords_html:30|safe }}` or `{{ post.content|truncatechars_html:30|safe }}`